# How to calculate the time interval of promo banner content using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

How to calculate the time interval of promo banner content using selenium web           driver

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the promo-banner is implemented.

Several options:

- regularly create a screenshot (and verify them against a ground truth)
- get the actual content of the banner (assuming its an image) and verify the URL
- query the DOM structure (assuming the promo banner vanishes after a while) and check when the element is gone (or no longer visible)

But without any code from you, or even any idea of how the promo-banner is implemented, this task is hard to solve exactly.